# SignalR transport will not work as websocket

Tags: websocket, signalr, self-hosting, owin

I have a bit of an issue.

I am using the self-hosting example (http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-signalr-self-host) and I have installed the 2.0 (beta2) packages from nuget.
I have my hub running on a webserver and my js client on my localhost.

Webserver is windows server 2012 with websockets enabled in roles.

My solution is set to target .NET 4.5 BUT has started out as 4.0. I have installed the nuget packages AFTER changing the solution target.

Client is running IE9 on Win7.

Now, when I check my referenced .dll's in Visual Studio their Runtime version is listed as 4.0. I am unsure if this means anything.

My problem is, I cannot connect my JS client to the hub, IF I tell it to use websockets.
If I don't specify websockets as transport, it connects fine, through longpolling.

What do I do? I have no idea what to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 does not support web sockets.

Comment: Oh crap, somehow I thought IE9 did. I even had our clients upgraded to IE9. :(